# Program to make a mouse an output device

Tags: camera, usb, mouse, driver

This question is extremely broad, but I am just looking for some direction to get me started.  I would like to make a program that works with a usb device to send a constant signal when the program says to.  I would like this program to use something I have laying around the house such as a mouse (That and the possibility of a wireless mouse is a bonus).

The idea is that I would have a transistor hooked to the terminal receiving the signal and when it turned on it would open the gate and work as a bulb for my camera, then when the signal stopped, the gate closes and my camera stops.

Can I write a program to make a HID do this, or would I have to write a driver to do this?

Any input would be super appreciated.

Comment: A mouse typically doesn't have any endpoints that you can send data to. You will have to find a different type of device (or something that supports rumble, lights, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**BETTER OPTION: ?**

You basically want to control external hardware with your computer. Instead of USB take a look at doing it over the serial port. It probably be much easier, especially if you want to send a signal to some hardware:

http://robotification.com/2008/05/23/serial-port-power-switch-with-net-control/

There are tons more resources available on serial communication. Just Google around a little bit.

**ORIGINAL answer:**

You don't need anything magical or a special driver to communicate with a USB port. You didn't mention any dev technology of choice but here's a .NET/C# article to get you started on working with USB:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/

Here's an open source lib (also C#): http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/

And a well-reviewed Code Project article with source code to get going: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/530836/Csharp-USB-HID-Interface

One thing that perplexes me about your question though. Why do you think the device has to be a mouse? It sounds like you just need something USB-capable to act as a bridge to controlling a camera.

Comment: I just said a mouse because I have one at home, and I figured HID driver would make it easier to connect it to a program someone has already written for the camera timer.  But I"m open to anything.

Comment: @user2348290: Consider doing it over serial. See my edit. I think you'll ba surprised at the number of fairly straightforward options you'll find.

Comment: I actually know how to do it over serial (Like you said, there are lots of options), but since most computers don't have serial ports any more I was hoping to cut out the middle man in the USB>Serial chain, and just use a USB device.

Answer (score 0):

Both as an input and output device, you can talk to an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) through the USB port, and those are about $30 now.... You would have a lot more success than trying to reverse engineer a mouse. There are tons of examples from both the hardware and software end for doing what you are talking about...